# How to use H264 DS Filter with Directshow GraphEdit

Tags: visual-c++, directshow, h.264, mp4, graphedit

I want to capture live video streams to .mp4 file. I have downloaded H264 DS Filter from http://hax264.sourceforge.net/. I want to generate Graph using GraphEdit utility of DirectShow. Can anyone please help me to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible with the link you posted:

> HAX264 is a DirectShow Video Transform Filter for decoding H264(AVC) video

You can try the [x264 DirectShow filter from Monogram](http://blog.monogram.sk/janos/2009/05/20/monogram-x264-encoder-1050/) or our open source [H264 DirectShow source filter](http://videoprocessing.sourceforge.net/) that implements limited parts of the H.264 specification.

You may also want to take a look at [Geraint Davies' mp4 mux](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/mpeg4/).

Comment: very useful infromation.

Comment: I'd also explicitly mention in the answer that HAX264 is a *decoding* filter, while what is clearly being asked in the question is how to *encode* ("compress") a captured stream [into an MP4 container with a H.264 video track].